# Pass user selection from InputBox to use as argument for Application.Run

Tags: excel, vba

How do I pass what the user selects to use as argument for Application.Run?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Sub Correlation()
Dim UserRange As Range
Dim UserSelect As Variant

'user selects the range
Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Title:="Correlation Analysis", Prompt:="Select range", Type:=8)
     UserSelect = Selection.Value

'function returns matrix of correlation coefficients based on the selected range
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Mcorrel", Worksheets("VBA").Selection.Value, Worksheets("Correl").Range("$a$2"), "C", True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected range of the user is in `UserRange` if you do the following. Note that I added some error handling so if the user presses cancel it exits.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Correlation()
    'user selects the range
    On Error Resume Next 'error handling so pressing cancel does not error
    Dim UserRange As Range
    Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Title:="Correlation Analysis", Prompt:="Select range", Type:=8)

    If UserRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'user pressed cancel
    On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activacte error reporting!!!


    'UserRange now referst to the selected range of the user
    Debug.Print UserRange.Address
End Sub
```

You can then use the variable `UserRange` to sumbit it as parameter

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Mcorrel", UserRange
'adjust it to your need.
```